# How do I create a lambda function to match a boost::function parameter without using C++0x?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

How do I create a lambda function using boost or the stl to match the `boost::function` parameter expected by `F` in the third snippet of code in `main`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

void F(int a, boost::function<bool(int)> f) {
    std::cout << "a = " << a << " f(a) = " << f(a) << std::endl;
}

bool G(int x) {
    return x == 0;
}

int main(int arg, char** argv) {
    // C++0x
    F(123, [](int i) { return i==0; } );

    // Using seperate function
    F(0, &G);

    // How can I do it in place without C++0x
    F(123, /* create a lambda here to match */);
}
```

I can't use C++0x and would like to avoid creating several separate functions.  I can use something other that `boost::function` if that helps, my priority is creating the lambda succinctly.

Comment: I am now wondering... how come that you cannot use C++0x but you want to use `std::function` that is part of C++0x? BTW, take a look at the boost lambda library, as it might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @David: boost::function not std::function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <functional>    // STL
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>   // Boost.Lambda
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>     // Boost.Pheonix
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp> // Boost.Pheonix also

...

// Use STL bind without lambdas
F(0, std::bind2nd(std::equal_to<int>(), 0));
F(123, std::bind2nd(std::equal_to<int>(), 0));

// Use Boost.Lambda (boost::lambda::_1 is the variable)
F(0, boost::lambda::_1 == 0);
F(123, boost::lambda::_1 == 0);

// Use Boost.Phoenix
F(0, boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1 == 0);
F(123, boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1 == 0);
```

You may want to add some `using namespace` to simplify the code.

[Boost.Lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/lambda.html) is strictly for defining functors inline with a C++-like syntax, while [Boost.Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/index.html) is a functional-programming language built on top of C++ abusing (☺) its syntax and compile-time computation capability. Boost.Phoenix is much more powerful than Boost.Lambda, but the former also takes much more time to compile.

Comment: Also, as of Boost 1.47, Boost.Lambda is officially deprecated in favor of Boost.Phoenix v3. I.e., Boost.Lambda is now a legacy library, not intended for use in new code.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: no.

C++0x lambdas were invented to do exactly what you want. They are actually nothing more than a way of making `Increment` in the below example anonymous/inline. It is the *only* way to get an anonymous function in any of the standard C++s.

```
struct Increment {
    int & arg;
    Increment (int a) : arg (a) {}
    void operator () (int & i)
        {arg += i;}
};

void foo (const std :: vector <int> & buffer, int x)
{
    std :: for_each (
        buffer .begin (), buffer .end (),
        Increment (x)); // C++98

    std :: for_each (
        buffer .begin (), buffer .end (),
        [&x] (int & i) {x += i;}); // C++0x
}
```

The only magical thing about lambdas is that their type cannot be spelled but the compiler can bind the internal hidden type to `std::function` (or even a C function pointer under some circumstances).

I'm posting the above code because I think your question might not mean what you think it does. *Lambdas* are definitely a C++0x thing but in this example, `Increment` is a *closure*. (Some would say it only becomes a closure if you return it and the bound variable escapes the context in which it was bound -- that's nitpicking but it's what, say, Javascript does).

Is your question about lambdas or closures?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? The code is solid. EDIT: Except the `Increment` constructor should take an `int&` not an `int`.

Comment: @Mike : Probably because there are multiple lambda libraries for C++03. (I didn't downvote.)

Comment: I think we're just disagreeing on what "lambda" means. The C++03 "lambda libraries" may *look* like lambdas, due to clever and difficult work by the authors, but they are *not* lambdas. I can't help but feel a bit hard-done-by :-(